# Pourquoi l'emprunt « liche » (de l'anglais « lich ») est-il ainsi suffixé et de genre féminin ?

Tags: anglais, genre, suffixes, emprunts

Dans une question portant sur la traduction de *lich* (un type de sorcier en genre littéraire merveilleux etc.), on a identifié *la liche*, nom féminin. Il s'agirait d'un [emprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liche_(cr%C3%A9ature)#Origine_du_mot) à l'[anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lich#Noun), suffixé avec *e*. Peut-on qualifier comment l'emprunt s'est fait et sa nature ; *liche* est-il un mot en suffixé en [-iche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-iche) ; les mots qui lui ressemblent sont-ils féminins et est-ce pertinent ? Pourquoi le mot contient-il un *e* final, pourquoi est-il féminin (*une liche*) et non épicène (*un/une liche*) ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2VBvBvZSB0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Les mots qui lui ressemblent sont-ils féminins et est-ce pertinent ?

Tous les mots composés d'une consonne suivie de *-iche* sont féminins:

- biche, fiche, miche, niche

> Pourquoi le mot contient-il un e final ?

Il existe très peu de mots en *-ich* en français et ils sont tous clairement d'origine étrangère (backchich, sandwich...). La prononciation de *-iche* est déterministe alors que celle d'*-ich* ne l'est pas (ex: *Munich*). Marcel Bich a d'ailleurs retiré le *h* final de son patronyme pour créer la marque *Bic*.

> Pourquoi est-il féminin (une liche) et non épicène (un/une liche) ?

Le genre du nom désignant une personne ou un animal n'est pas nécessairement lié à son sexe: une vigie, canaille, crapule, fripouille, racaille, antilope, guèpe, mouche, panthère, souris...

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Oui. Déterminisme : *Principe scientifique d'après lequel tout phénomène est régi par une (ou plusieurs) loi(s) nécessaire(s) telle(s) que les mêmes causes entraînent dans les mêmes conditions ou circonstances, les mêmes effets.* et déterministe : * [En parlant d'un processus] Qui obéit aux lois du déterminisme*.

Comment: D'accord, est-ce qu'une prononciation déterministe est « prévisible » pour le locuteur ; y a-t-il adéquation ? Je ne savais pas pour _Bic_, mais je crois que l'exemple implique que oui ? Merci !

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Oui, c'est bien ça. J'aurais pu mettre prévisible pour *-iche* et incertaine pour *-ich*. Marcel Bich prononçait *bik* et c'est pour lever l’ambiguïté, en particulier pour un nom de marque aux ambitions l'internationales, qu'il a retiré le *h*.

Comment: Lire: ...aux ambitions internationales...

Answer (score 3):

La liche est aussi un [poisson](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liche_(poisson)). 
Donc, c'était déjà un nom féminin avant l'importation du mot anglais.

Comment: Oui, mais la liche dont on parle dans la question n'est pas un poisson. Le genre d'un mot préexistant, surtout quand ce mot est inconnu de (quasiment) tous, n'influe pas forcément sur ses homonymes. **La moule** n'empêche pas **le moule**...

Comment: C'est vrai... Je crois que pour savoir si ça a eu une influence, il nous faudrait une thèse sur le sujet^^